# Vertical align icon with multiline text

Tags: html, css

I have following CSS:

```
.dropdown section h4::after {
    content: url(img/plus-symbol.svg);
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Can somebody give me a little hint on how to bring "+" icon to the middle in the last item?

[image]

Comment: play with top value .. try `top:45%`

Comment: Try adding those two rules: `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li:after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But I am using like section h4 div::after{content:" "}, I am not using ul li :(

Answer (score 1):

```
.dropdown section h4 {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown section h4::after {
    content: url(img/plus-symbol.svg);
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

More information about [browser compatibility of transform](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)
The `transform: translate()` property allows you to move an element relative to his height or width. So if you're + icon does have an height of 40px, transform: translateY(-50%) will move up you element of 20px.

You could also have a look to `display: table-cell` to use `vertical-align: middle`, but it might depends of your HTML structure. :)

Another solution is the use of [flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).